# About Calculator in asm 8086 - 2 Questions

Tags: assembly, x86-16

for my finale project im working on a calculator in assembly- Tasm- 8086,till now everything went great but now im having hard time figure out how to "know" the nums that were in the input.
I made it so that all the numbers and the Actions (*/+=^) are going into array.
but now im kinda stuck cause i dont know how to check if the first num was- 1,2,3,4 or 5 digits till the action. and then i also need to check the second num that enterd.
that was the first question.
The second question is that if someone know how to combine keyboard and mouse input together?
at the moment i have mouse input works absolutly fine but im having hard time with the keyboard.

I took out some of the proc that im struggling on with the keyboard and mouse. 
(thats the keyboard):

```
in al, 64h         ; Read keyboard status port
cmp al, 10b        ; Data in buffer ?
je AfterLooping              ; Wait until data available    
in al, 60h         ; Get keyboard data
cmp al,'+'
je ToPrint
cmp al,'-'
je ToPrint
cmp al,'/'
je ToPrint
cmp al,'X'
je ToPrint
cmp al,'^'
je ToPrint
cmp al,'='
je ToPrint
cmp al,'0'
jb continuethepros
cmp al,'9'
ja continuethepros
```

to print is a label that called to a proc of printing where i need and in the correct color. and continuethepros is a label  that mov on this part and then check if the button esc was entered ..

Thanks.
by the way- sorry about my language idk if i spelled everything correctly.

Comment: You need to store the digits somewhere until you need them. A good way to do this is to convert them from ASCII decimal digits to binary numbers while do this. Eg. so you if `'5'` is pressed the stored value becomes '5', if '6'` is then pressed then stored value becomes `56`, and so on.

Comment: i dont get it.. and why does it matter if its binari or asci or decimal

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the actual code that you've written, answering the first question is tricky. But here's a thought:

```
if number smaller than 10  --> 1 digit
else if number smaller than 100  --> 2 digits
else if number smaller than 1000  --> 3 digits
else if number smaller than 10000  --> 4 digits
else if number smaller than 100000  --> 5 digits
```

---

For the second question I can give these observations:

- To see if you got data in the keyboard buffer you need to `test` bit 1 and not just compare the whole AL register!
- The data that you obtain from port 60h is not an ASCII code but rather a scan code. When you write an instruction like `cmp al,'X'` the assembler will substitute the `'X'` with an ASCII, but you need a scancode!

This is how:

```
in   al, 64h         ; Read keyboard status port
test al, 10b         ; Data in buffer ?
jz   AfterLooping    ; Wait until data available    
in   al, 60h         ; Get keyboard data
cmp  al, 2Dh         ; Scancode of 'X', ASCII is 78h
je   ToPrint
```